# Error When Running stack ghci on my MacOS Terminal

Tags: haskell

I am getting this error when I try to run stack ghci on my Mac Termina. How do I resolve this? I've run stack upgrade and stack update.

```
Downloading lts-18.13 build plan ...RedownloadFailed Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-18.13.yaml"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
```

Comment: Is your Mac an M1 Chipset? If so, I think there is a chance that is the issue. If it is an M1, you could run it under Rosetta and that should work.

Comment: My Mac has Intel and not M1 Chip.